# Wrapping <td>'s within a <tr>

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a simple HTML way to accomplish the following?  I have a table which contains rows of 3 `td`'s each.  Items are added to the table at the top, so it is sorted in reverse order.  See below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, when the time comes for me to add 8 to the top of my table, obviously I must do a lot of editing to the page rather than just add one new line.  I'd like to do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr max-cells-before-wrap="3">
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I'm not sure if it's possible in HTML.  I could write a simple JS function to do it, but basic HTML would be even cooler.

Comment: HTML does allow for columns/column groups in standard tables, but they're a pain to use: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html

Comment: You can achieve this functionality with UL/LI elements.

Comment: I hope I'm not crucified for short-sightedness, but jQuery or a comparable library could ease this with `$.prepend()`. I'm not sure if IE's weirdo handling of `table` manipulation negates this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could always try something like this...

```
<table width="200">
<tr>
<td>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">7</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">6</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">5</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">4</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">3</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">2</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">1</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and just add

```
<div style="float:left; width: 33%">8</div>
```

right before 7

Comment: This is only barely approximating @ŠimeVidas' answer, embedded in a table no less.

Comment: Are people still using tables? You could get rid of the parent table, replacing it with a parent div.

Comment: Thanks, Chris M.  I like this solution best.  And yes @Coomie, I am still using tables.  They remain the easiest solution for vertically centering cell content across all browsers.  And if that doesn't blow your mind enough, consider this: in the code above, I am putting a single cell table in each div! :-)  Again... easy universal centering at the expense of an ugly and illogical line of code.  Lesser evil of all options IMO.

Comment: @The111 I'm racist against tables, but even I can admit they have their places - their 3 very specific places: HTML emails, tabular data and vertical spacing. But even then I'd look into using jQuery to read the height of the text and add margin-top...

Answer (score 2):

May I propose this?

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li>7</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3n4FE/

Comment: No. You may not. LOL. Crazy talk, son.

Comment: Seems to work fairly well, but some of the CSS stuff for `ul` elements is finicky cross browser, so I'm sticking with the other solution with `div`s.  Thanks for the alternative approach though, and theoretically a more simple approach, if MSIE wasn't there to make all of our lives difficult.

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. The goes against the notion of a **t** able **r** ow does it not?