# Displaying new line without using <TR> in html page by wrapping TD tags

Tags: html, jsp, xhtml

I need to display multiple lines in one row without using "TR" tag.

This is necessary because I am applying sortabletable.js on my JSP so when sorting rows which are to be considered as single entity then it fails.

I tried the following:

```
<table style="display:inline-block" width="90px">
    <tr>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td width="30px">1</td>
        <td width="30px">1</td>

        <td width="30px">2</td>
        <td width="30px">2</td>
        <td width="30px">2</td>

        <td width="30px">3</td>
        <td width="30px">3</td>
        <td width="30px">3</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Can the TD in 3rd row be wrapped into 3 lines by restricting the row and table length?

The following code was working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<style>
#table_id  {display: block; }
#table_id  td {display: inline-block;float:left; }
</style>


<table id="table_id" style="width:55px;table-layout:fixed" border="1">


<tr>

<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>

<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>

<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You can create new table in the cell) or some other markup

Comment: @vp_arth: Is it possible to display in multiple lines by restricting the length. If a new table is introduced then sorting of rows of the whole table is not possible

Comment: @vp_arth: Thanks. Is it possible to wrap the 2nd and 3rd lines by restricting the row length?

Comment: Can u let me know whats wrong with the given example. why the 3rd row is not wrapped as 3 lines in the table

Comment: If you want to wrap 9 td-cells, it's not possible, I think. Not with tables, you complete cancel all table styles while doing this)

Comment: check also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821496/wrapping-tds-within-a-tr)

Comment: This is not just table abuse, this is plain torture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this with nested tables: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/98Z9G/)

```
<td width="30px">
  <table>
    <tr><td width="30px">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="30px">4</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="30px">5</td></tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

And here without nested tables:

```
<td width="30px" style="white-space: pre;">
  3
  4
  5
</td>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/98Z9G/1/)

By width limiting also:

```
<td style="word-break:break-word;width:10px;">345</td>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/98Z9G/2/)

Comment: Please post the relevant code to solve the problem **here** in your answer. Providing fiddles are good as a demonstration of your proposed answer.

Comment: first fiddle is not relevant, but all meaningful part of second I post here.

Comment: Even if not relevant, the answer must be posted here, not in the fiddles.

Comment: I simple unwanted to post here a nested tables garbage, there is not some kind of spoiler...